# Mock Mule JavaComponent

Tags: java, web-services, testing, mocking, mule

I have a flow like this in mule 3.3.1

http--->JavaComponent (call WebService through SoapWS.java)---->setPayLoad----> Http Endpoint

the problem: I need to write test for this flow but I don't know how mock SoapWS.java.

I'm writting automated tests so i can't change the class manually It has to be automatic.

Answer (score 1):

Use Spring to inject the "caller" to the web service in your Java component. At test time, inject a stub.

Extract the configuration of this "caller" in another Mule XML configuration. At test time, load the main configuration and a test one that contains the stubs.